# Why the vertex count is getting only in Development mode in DSE Graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

When I try to get vertex count in DSE Graph using

> g.V().count()

in Production mode below error is displaying.

```
Could not find a suitable index to answer graph query and graph scans are disabled
```

But the same is working in Development mode. Am I doing something wrong.

I am trying quick start link but created my own schema

https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/QuickStartStudio.html

Schema:

> schema.propertyKey("id").Int().single().create()
>   schema.propertyKey("name").Text().single().create()
>
> schema.edgeLabel("created").multiple().create()
>
> schema.vertexLabel("feed").properties("id").create()
>   schema.vertexLabel("user").properties("id", "name").create()
>
> schema.vertexLabel("feed").index("byFeedId").materialized().by("id").add()
>   schema.vertexLabel("user").index("byUser").materialized().by("id").add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Counting across your vertexes is an expensive query that is not expected to be done in production in an OLTP use case.

#### Why?

Vertices are stored in an adjacency list by vertex type in DSE Graph and to get a count of all the vertices you would have to do a full table scan for each of these which is impractical in a distributed transactional system (you'd have to hit an entire replica set which could be a lot of nodes).

#### It's a real query. What do I do?

If this is a real use case, it is probably an analytical use case in which case you should be leveraging the spark graph computer by running the query in analytics mode.
Note: the full table scan may still take time but it will be executed in massively distributed fashion via DSE Analytics.